# How can I revoke a token using PayPal API

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have a website with two payment processors:

The other processor have an API call to invalidate a token, so if the user still didn't submit his payment info and I revoked his pending payment token -> he'll get an error.

#### There's a scenario where a (crazy) user can pay using both payment gateways:

```
1. The user starts a request to paypal
2. The user starts a request to other processor
3. He completes the payment with other processor
4. He then completes the payment with paypal
```

As I can see it, only *revoking* the paypal token can solve this condition.
If so - does anyone know how to do it programmatically?

Note: Any situation where two transactions are completed successfully is unacceptable (so refund/cancel and similar is not a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the (popular) express checkout API, and that the situation you're describing is AFTER you've issued a `SetExpressCheckout` but BEFORE you issued the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`.
In that case, as you already redirected the shopper to the PayPal site, it's out of your hands and there's no API to revoke the token. However, there's a simple solution to your case. Even if the shopper approved the transaction at PayPal, you can still ignore the redirect and NOT issue a `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` request. In this case, the captured funds from his account (which you never got), will be returned to him 3 hours after the initial SetExpressCheckout was issues.
Don't forget to issue a proper notification to the user.

Comment: Indeed - I'm using PayPal Express Checkout, and it really solves this issue. Thanks